# Ramda: pass predicate equality argument last

Tags: ramda.js

I heve a static collection. And I want to check for any match by value each time, the value is changed.

Now I have:

```
var isOk = R.any(item => item.test(value), items);
```

What I want:

To store a function in other place and to call it like:

```
var isOk = checkMatch(value);
```

Any ideas? Thx.

**UPDATE**
I'm looking for solution in Ramda way. Something with changind call order of R.__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure that your test items are regular expressions to use on 
Strings, but if they are, you might try something like this:

```
const anyMatch = curry((regexes, val) => any(regex => test(regex, val), regexes))

const testFiles = anyMatch([/test\/(.)+\.js/i, /\.spec\.js/i])

testFiles('foo.js') //=> false
testFiles('test/foo.js') //=> true
testFiles('foo.spec.js') //=> true
```

And this looks clean to me, and very much in the spirit of Ramda.  If you wanted to make it point-free, you could do this:

```
const anyMatch = useWith(flip(any), [identity, flip(test)])
```

But I find that much less readable.  To me, point-free is a tool worth using when it improves readability, and to avoid when it doesn't.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20anyMatch%20%3D%20curry%28%28regexes%2C%20val%29%20%3D%3E%20any%28regex%20%3D%3E%20test%28regex%2C%20val%29%2C%20regexes%29%29%0A%2F%2F%20const%20anyMatch%20%3D%20useWith%28flip%28any%29%2C%20%5Bidentity%2C%20flip%28test%29%5D%29%0A%0Aconst%20testFiles%20%3D%20anyMatch%28%5B%2Ftest%5C%2F%28.%29%2B%5C.js%2Fi%2C%20%2F%5C.spec%5C.js%2Fi%5D%29%0A%0AtestFiles%28%27foo.js%27%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20false%0AtestFiles%28%27test%2Ffoo.js%27%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20true%0AtestFiles%28%27foo.spec.js%27%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20true%0A)**.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I was looking for. Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a closure that takes `value`.

```
var isOk = (value) => R.any(item => item.test(value), items);

var isOk_foobar = isOk('foobar');
```

Comment: Well, I meant to do it the Ramda way :) Something with composition or R.__. But ofc you're right.